# Unable to start file "..\ntoskrnl.exe" in ollydbg [What can I do?]

Tags: assembly

Ollydbg isn't allowing me to open the executable ntoskrnl. I think im missing something but I don't know what it is (Windows 7, Ollydbg10.0,200)

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. What's your goal? You seem to be trying to load the kernel PE file from usermode as if it was any PE file and as if it were suitable to be run inside the Win32 subsystem. Could you please tell us what it is you want to achieve, rather than asking about _your perceived way_ of getting there? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Im trying to locate and dump disassembly  of the exports for ntoskrnl.exe. Thanx for replying

Comment: And using OllyDbg is a hard requirement? Why not use a more suitable tool for the task, such as IDA, Hopper, Ghidra, Cutter/r2?

Comment: Thanx for the heads up man :) I really am terrible still. I have been trying to learn these tools tho

Comment: windbg -z ntoskrnl.exe ;!showexports